# Why does os.path use both '\' and '/'?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, anaconda

When I get the `os.path.dirname()` of a file on Windows, it uses the / character (gets converted to \ by Windows), but then when I `os.path.join()` that path with other things, it uses the \ character (as expected).

```
import os

cwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)
print(cwd)                            # C:/Users/me/Documents/dir1
parent_dir = os.path.join(cwd, '..')
print(parent_dir)                     # C:/Users/me/Documents/dir1\..
```

Windows handles this just fine. As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx):

> File I/O functions in the Windows API convert "/" to "\" as part of converting the name to an NT-style name, except when using the "\\?\" prefix as detailed in the following sections.

But why does the use of both slashes occuring in the first place?

**EDITS:**

I run the command using `python myfile.py` from Cygwin shell.

I am using the [Anaconda3](https://www.continuum.io/anaconda-overview) distribution, which is installed at `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe`.

```
λ which python
/cygdrive/c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/python
```

Comment: cannot reproduce the slashes on windows (first output). How do you run your python file?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I am using Anaconda, see my edit.

Comment: are you running it from cygwin by chance?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it is running from `/cygdrive/c`

Comment: edited (added "from Cygwin shell"). Hope it's OK.

Comment: There are more places than just ``\\?\`` paths where you can be bitten by using forward slashes in Windows (e.g. command-line arguments and anything that uses native paths under the hood; such as ``Global\`` kernel object names and registry paths). For the filesystem API, forward slash is allowed because runtime library functions such as `RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U_WithStatus` do the conversion for you. But for consistency it's often better to just do it yourself. `pathlib` in Python 3 handles this for you, and in 3.6 it's broadly supported by the standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're running from cygwin, the paths are not native, but altered for cygwin to be able to work properly (MSYS does the same).

So as a side effect, when python asks for current file, it is returned with slashes.

BUT anaconda is still a native windows distribution, which explains that you get `\` (native `os.sep`) when joining strings.

To get `__file__` path with native separators (`\` here), just do:

```
os.path.normpath(__file__)
```